# i want to display submitted values?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

here is my code!!

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      res.write('File uploaded');
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
   res.write('User name:<br> <input type="Text" Name="User Name"><br>');
   res.write('User Phone:<br><input type="Text" Name="User Phone"><br>');
   res.write('User E-mail:<br><input type="Text" Name="User E-mail"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    console.log();
    return res.end();

  }
}).listen(8080);
```

i want to display all submitted values that i used in this code.
kindly help me whats wrong in this code!!

Comment: What problem you are facing ?

Comment: `console.log(fields)` or `res.write(JSON.stringify(fields));`

Comment: This would be really easy in a framework such as Vue.js Are you using any framework? https://012.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Comment: show your log here

Comment: well actually i want to display submitted values as a form like all values printed as a form name just like id card or license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print values in console:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(fields));
console.log(files);
```

print values on web page:

```
res.write(JSON.stringify(fields));
console.log(files);
```